# trixie/sid/testing:Debian Trixie Variant Displaying as 'trixie/sid':

Tags: debian, conventions

I currently have Debian Trixie installed on my system. When I run the command `lsb_release -a`, it returns the output `Description: Debian GNU/Linux trixie/sid`. However, I was under the impression that "trixie" corresponds to the testing variant rather than the "sid" (unstable) branch. To further investigate this, I experimented with various Docker images such as `debian:trixie, debian:sid`, and `debian:testing`. All of these Docker images also displayed the description as `Debian GNU/Linux trixie/sid`. Is this because Trixie (Debian Testing) is still associated with the "sid" (unstable) repositories?